# Android Camera takePicture function does not call Callback function

Tags: android, camera, android-camera

I am working on a custom Camera activity for my application.
I was following the instruction from the Android Developers site here:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html
Everything seems to works fine, except the Callback function is not called and the picture is not saved. Here is my code:

```
public class CameraActivity extends Activity {
private Camera mCamera;
private CameraPreview mPreview;
private static final String TAG = "CameraActivity";

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.camera);

    // Create an instance of Camera
    mCamera = getCameraInstance();

    // Create our Preview view and set it as the content of our activity.
    mPreview = new CameraPreview(this, mCamera);
    FrameLayout preview = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.camera_preview);
    preview.addView(mPreview);

    Button captureButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_capture);
    captureButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.v(TAG, "will now take picture");
            mCamera.takePicture(null, null, mPicture);
            Log.v(TAG, "will now release camera");
            mCamera.release();
            Log.v(TAG, "will now call finish()");
            finish();
        }
    });        
}

private PictureCallback mPicture = new PictureCallback() {

    @Override
    public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
        Log.v(TAG, "Getting output media file");
        File pictureFile = getOutputMediaFile();
        if (pictureFile == null) {
            Log.v(TAG, "Error creating output file");
            return;
        }
        try {
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(pictureFile);
            fos.write(data);
            fos.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            Log.v(TAG, e.getMessage());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.v(TAG, e.getMessage());
        }
    }
};

private static File getOutputMediaFile() {
    String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
    if (!state.equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) {
        return null;
    }
    else {
        File folder_gui = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "GUI");
        if (!folder_gui.exists()) {
            Log.v(TAG, "Creating folder: " + folder_gui.getAbsolutePath());
            folder_gui.mkdirs();
        }
        File outFile = new File(folder_gui, "temp.jpg");
        Log.v(TAG, "Returnng file: " + outFile.getAbsolutePath());
        return outFile;
    }
}
```

After clicking the Button, I get logs: "will now take picture", "will now release camera" and "will now call finish". The activity finishes succesfully, but the Callback function was not called during the

```
mCamera.takePicture(null, null, mPicture);
```

function (There were no logs from the mPicture callback or getMediaOutputFile functions) and there is no file in the location that was specified.

Any ideas? :)
Much thanks!

Comment: I need some help for same in C#.. Please

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The call to `mCamera.takePicture()` is asynchronous. That means that the call completes immediately, but the actual picture taking and processing happens sometime later. However, you do this immediately upon return from the call to `mCamera.takePicture()`:

```
Log.v(TAG, "will now release camera");
mCamera.release();
Log.v(TAG, "will now call finish()");
finish();
```

That means that you have released the camera resources and finished the Activity before the camera gets a chance to actually take the picture and call you back.

You need to move that code into the callback method `onPictureTaken()` so that you release the resources and finish the Activity after the callback occurs.

Comment: Well that was simple...i'm kindda surprised I couldn't find a similar question here. Anyway, that did it, thank you very much :)

Comment: I am not calling `mCamera.release()` nor `finish()`, and still having this problem.  So something else may be going on.

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky maybe you should open a new question instead of adding a comment to this answer. Obviously your situation is different. The original poster seemed satisfied with this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this for taking multiple images on single Click Using SurfaceView Custom Camera

```
clickbtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                mcamera = mPreview.getCamera();

                getimage(mcamera);

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "multiple image count=" + i, 1000).show();

            }

            if (mPreview == null) {
                mPreview = new CamLayer(MainActivity.this);
            }


        }
    });
```

and

```
    public static void getimage(Camera mcamera) {


    PictureCallback mPicture = new PictureCallback() {

        @Override
        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
            pictureFile = getOutputMediaFile();
            Log.e("path file 11111111", ""+pictureFile);
            if (pictureFile == null) {
                return;
            }
            try {
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(pictureFile);
                fos.write(data);
                fos.close();

            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

            } catch (Exception e) {

            }
        }
    };
    try {

        mcamera.startPreview();
        mcamera.takePicture(null, null, mPicture);
        Thread.sleep(2000);

    } catch (Exception exception) {
        exception.printStackTrace();
    }

}

private static File getOutputMediaFile() {
    File mediaStorageDir = new File(
            Environment
                    .getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES),
            "Sunil3");
    if (!mediaStorageDir.exists()) {
        if (!mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()) {

            return null;
        }
    }


    File mediaFile = new File(String.format(mediaStorageDir+File.separator+"%d.jpg", System.currentTimeMillis()));

    return mediaFile;
}
```

Comment: Why are you passing nulls to `takePicture` method params?