# Camera takePicture() does not call onPictureTaken() callback even though camera isn't released

Tags: android, android-camera

I put a debug breakpoint inside the onPictureTaken() callback and it wasn't hit when I tapped the phone screen although onTouch() and takePicture() were being called. Therefore, takePicture() isn't calling the callback inside onTouch(). However, it does work inside the onClickListener() for the Button. I followed the Android Developer website Camera API example, and added the TouchListener part on my own. I looked at this question [Android Camera takePicture function does not call Callback function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19687324/android-camera-takepicture-function-does-not-call-callback-function) but the camera was never released anywhere that I'm aware of. Sorry for the bad code indentation; Control + k brings up Google Search in Chrome for the first post. Here is the full code:

```
public class CameraActivity extends Activity {

private Camera mCamera;
private CameraPreview mPreview;

Camera.PictureCallback mPicture;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Create an instance of Camera
    mCamera = getCameraInstance();

    // Create our Preview view and set it as the content of our activity.
    mPreview = new CameraPreview(this, mCamera);
    FrameLayout preview = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.camera_preview);
    preview.addView(mPreview);
    mPreview.setOnTouchListener(new TouchListener());

    mPicture = new Camera.PictureCallback() {

        @Override
        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {

            File pictureFile = getOutputMediaFile(MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE);
            if (pictureFile == null){
                Log.d(TAG, "Error creating media file, check storage permissions");
                return;
            }

            try {
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(pictureFile);
                fos.write(data);
                fos.close();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                Log.d(TAG, "File not found: " + e.getMessage());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Error accessing file: " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    };

    Button captureButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_capture);
    captureButton.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // get an image from the camera
                    mCamera.takePicture(null, null, mPicture);

                }
            }
    );
}

boolean safeToTakePicture = true;
public class TouchListener implements View.OnTouchListener {

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {


        while (!safeToTakePicture) {
        }
        safeToTakePicture = false;
        mCamera.takePicture(null, null, mPicture);
        return true;
    }
}


public static Camera getCameraInstance(){
    Camera c = null;
    try {
        c = Camera.open(); // attempt to get a Camera instance
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        // Camera is not available (in use or does not exist)
    }
    return c; // returns null if camera is unavailable
}

public static final int MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE = 1;
public static final int MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO = 2;

/** Create a file Uri for saving an image or video */
private static Uri getOutputMediaFileUri(int type){
    return Uri.fromFile(getOutputMediaFile(type));
}

/** Create a File for saving an image or video */
private static File getOutputMediaFile(int type){
    // To be safe, you should check that the SDCard is mounted
    // using Environment.getExternalStorageState() before doing this.

    File mediaStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
            Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "MyCameraApp");
    // This location works best if you want the created images to be shared
    // between applications and persist after your app has been uninstalled.

    // Create the storage directory if it does not exist
    if (! mediaStorageDir.exists()){
        if (! mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()){
            Log.d("MyCameraApp", "failed to create directory");
            return null;
        }
    }

    // Create a media file name
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    File mediaFile;
    if (type == MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE){
        mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator +
                "IMG_"+ timeStamp + ".jpg");
    } else if(type == MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO) {
        mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator +
                "VID_"+ timeStamp + ".mp4");
    } else {
        return null;
    }

    return mediaFile;
}
}


public class CameraPreview extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
public SurfaceHolder mHolder;
private Camera mCamera;

public CameraPreview(Context context, Camera camera) {
    super(context);
    mCamera = camera;

    // Install a SurfaceHolder.Callback so we get notified when the
    // underlying surface is created and destroyed.
    mHolder = getHolder();
    mHolder.addCallback(this);
    // deprecated setting, but required on Android versions prior to 3.0
    mHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
}

public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    // The Surface has been created, now tell the camera where to draw the preview.
    try {
        mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
        mCamera.startPreview();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.d("Error", "Error setting camera preview: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}

public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    // empty. Take care of releasing the Camera preview in your activity.
}

public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int w, int h) {
     }
}
}
```

Comment: You may see some clues in the full logcat. One caveat could be that you don't set picture size and format. Some devices will use acceptable defaults, but other devices may get stuck.

Comment: refer link  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53811048/capture-multiple-images-from-camera-and-send-all-to-server/53812370#53812370